# understanding RCpp compile

Tags: r, rcpp

I was looking at the `verbose=TRUE` when I tried to `sourceCpp` a Rcpp file. The last output is:

```
DIR: C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmielLn/sourcecpp_226416891d0e

C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o "sourceCpp_22129.dll" --preclean "myfile.cpp" 
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/xyz/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c myfile.cpp -o myfile.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_22129.dll tmp.def myfile.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
```

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. the 1nd `g++` command refers to `-I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"` and the 2nd command refers to `-Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64` and `-Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib` . But I don't have a `D:` drive, or a `RCompile` folder anywhere. What do these things refer to?
2. I tried to manually run the 1st `g++` which ran file and created `myfun.o` file, but when I tried to manually run the 2nd `g++` it gave me an error saying that it couldn't find the `tmp.def` file. I couldn't find the `tmp.def` file anywhere on my drives. Where would this `tmp.def` file located?
3. I looked under the hood of `sourceCpp` function. if I directly run the definition of `cmd` in the `sourceCpp` function: `C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o "sourceCpp_22129.dll" --preclean "myfile.cpp"` on Windows' command window , I noticed that it does not include `-I"C:/Users/xyz/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"` and the `R CMD SHLIB` gives me an error.

How does the `system(cmd, ..)` within the `sourceCpp` function include this? The value of the `cmd` variable in the `sourceCpp` didn't include `-I"C:/Users/xyz/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include"`

Comment: The entire setup of how the compilation  works, and how you would do it by hand, is discussed in Chapter 2 of the [Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book) as well. You may find reading a more complete exposition more rewarding than trying random commands copied from the screen.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks. In a hurry to write Rcpp C++ codes to improve the speed of my R codes, I had completely skipped over the Chapter 2 of your book. Reading it now.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, one more question: why is the CLINK_CPPFLAGS not visible in Windows' User / System environment variables window, when it is set within `sourceCpp` by the `.setupBuildEnvironment` function. I couldn't find answer in the book

Comment: Note the call to `.restoreEnvironment` -- it restores the old environment after `sourceCpp` has finished being envoked. I suggest stepping through `sourceCpp` with a debugger (ie, `debug(sourceCpp)`) and studying how the environment changes / code is executed yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the 1nd g++ command refers to -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include" and the 2nd command refers to -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 and -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib . But I don't have a D: drive, or a RCompile folder anywhere. What do these things refer to?

AFAIK these are left in as part of the CRAN R Windows distribution; when R binaries are built on Windows they use something in these library paths on the build servers (but stay baked into R anyhow). You can safely ignore it, but it is a bit odd. Unused / non-existent directories passed through `gcc` / `g++` are just ignored.

> I tried to manually run the 1st g++ which ran file and created myfun.o file, but when I tried to manually run the 2nd g++ it gave me an error saying that it couldn't find the tmp.def file. I couldn't find the tmp.def file anywhere on my drives. Where would this tmp.def file located?

`tmp.def`, as it sounds, is a temporary definition file created by `R CMD SHLIB` on Windows. If you just re-run what you see it does not get generated, so I suppose R does something behind the curtains to generate it. If you are curious about where it's generated, see `share/make/winshlib.mk` in the R sources.

> I looked under the hood of sourceCpp function. if I directly run the definition of cmd in the sourceCpp function: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o "sourceCpp_22129.dll" --preclean "myfile.cpp" on Windows' command window , I noticed that it does not include -I"C:/Users/xyz/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" and the R CMD SHLIB gives me an error.

This is because `sourceCpp` is setting the appropriate environment flags behind the scenes for you as well -- in this case, the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable. This gets automatically done on package installs as well when the `LinkingTo:` entry is specified in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: thanks. Question: which part / lines in the sourceCpp files handle / refers / uses the `CXXFLAGS` ? And why isn't the  `CXXFLAGS` include when I run the same `cmd` variable on Windows' command window?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that is not quite correct. It is `Rcpp:::.buildClinkCppFlags` doing the work, e.g. see what `Rcpp:::.buildClinkCppFlags("Rcpp")` gives you. This is set for the `CLINK_CPPFLAGS` variable. Try browsing `R/Attributes.R` in Rcpp.

Comment: thanks. I noticed that the `.setupBuildEnvironment` within the `sourceCpp` file calls `.buildClinkCppFlags` which in turn sets the `CLINK_CPPFLAGS` variable. Would you know where the `CLINK_CPPFLAGS` variable is un-set?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar g++ compilation command as posted in the question, and the compilation of a very simple C function didn't work for me.

The reason it didn't work is the following option shown in the g++ command:
-I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"

which adds an include directory on a drive that does not exist on my computer. Apparently non-existent directories listed in the -I option are ignored by g++ (as stated by Kevin Ushey) but this seems not to be the case for non-existent *drives*.

The error message I received was that the sdtlib.h header file was not found:

> C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/include/R.h:28:20: fatal error:
>   d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include/stdlib.h: Input/output
>   error  #include

In order to remove the offending -I option from the g++ command I had to edit the Makeconf file located in $(R_HOME}/etc$(R_ARCH) (in my case C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\etc\x64) and comment out the line:

> LOCAL_SOFT = d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320